# php - adding totals for list of clients in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looping through a list of client names to get their total minutes used for a service. The problem is, each client has more than one database so I have to loop through those too, and then add the totals associated with each client. I'm not able to add the results for each client. What am I doing wrong?

PHP

```
foreach ($clients as $client) {
    foreach ($dbNew as $d) {
        $result += (strtotime($closing_time[$x]->log_time) - strtotime($opening_time[$x]->log_time));

        print "<pre>";
        print_r($client);
        print " --- ";
        print_r($result);
        print "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Output

```
adarty@cfl_rr.com --- 425
adarty@cfl_rr.com --- 225
doug --- 0
doug --- 0
rforgo@gmail.com --- 0
rforgo@gmail.com --- 4357
rforgo@gmail.com --- 336
```

PHP to get client totals (feeble attempt):

```
$client_result = 0;
if($client == $client)
$client_result = $result + $result;
```

The results from this are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get the question correctly, each client accesses in different times and put in different sources. Well in that case u can use a unique field of the client (something like the email) to build another.

```
$res = array();
foreach ($clients as $client) {
    foreach ($dbNew as $d) {
       $result += (strtotime($closing_time[$x]->log_time) - strtotime($opening_time[$x]->log_time));

        print "<pre>";
        print_r($client);
        if(isset($res[$client[0]])){
       //i guessed the first field of $client is the email
       //if the client is already added to the $res list add the current time to it
            $res[$client[0]] += $result;
        }else{
        //else this is the first instance of the client....
            $res[$client[0]] = $result;
        }
        print " --- ";
        print_r($result);
        print "</pre>";
  }
}
```

then u can print `$res` here!

Comment: That's it! Except no need for the "[0]" on $client, but your notes were a great help too. Thank you!